# How can i handle big nested json data in java?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

i have a json data that is returned by the api.

I want to access forecast > forecastday > date object. How can i
access this data? Thx

```
{"location":{"name":"Bursa","region":"Bursa","country":"Turkey","lat":40.19,"lon":29.06,"tz_id":"Europe/Istanbul","localtime_epoch":1649793994,"localtime":"2022-04-12 23:06"},"current":{"last_updated_epoch":1649790000,"last_updated":"2022-04-12 22:00","temp_c":5.6,"temp_f":42.1,"is_day":0,"condition":{"text":"Clear","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png","code":1000},"wind_mph":2.2,"wind_kph":3.6,"wind_degree":158,"wind_dir":"SSE","pressure_mb":1022.0,"pressure_in":30.19,"precip_mm":0.0,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":74,"cloud":16,"feelslike_c":5.6,"feelslike_f":42.1,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"uv":1.0,"gust_mph":2.0,"gust_kph":3.2},"forecast":{"forecastday":[{"date":"2022-04-12","date_epoch":1649721600,"day":{"maxtemp_c":11.1,"maxtemp_f":52.0,"mintemp_c":3.3,"mintemp_f":37.9,"avgtemp_c":6.8,"avgtemp_f":44.2,"maxwind_mph":6.9,"maxwind_kph":11.2,"totalprecip_mm":2.4,"totalprecip_in":0.09,"avgvis_km":9.8,"avgvis_miles":6.0,"avghumidity":73.0,"daily_will_it_rain":1,"daily_chance_of_rain":81,"daily_will_it_snow":0,"daily_chance_of_snow":0,"condition":{"text":"Patchy rain possible","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/176.png","code":1063},"uv":5.0},"astro":{"sunrise":"06:30 AM","sunset":"07:39 PM","moonrise":"02:54 PM","moonset":"04:38 AM","moon_phase":"Waxing Gibbous","moon_illumination":"77"},"hour":[{"time_epoch":1649710800,"time":"2022-04-12 00:00","temp_c":4.4,"temp_f":39.9,"is_day":0,"condition":{"text":"Clear","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png","code":1000},"wind_mph":2.7,"wind_kph":4.3,"wind_degree":270,"wind_dir":"W","pressure_mb":1021.0,"pressure_in":30.15,"precip_mm":0.0,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":85,"cloud":21,"feelslike_c":3.7,"feelslike_f":38.7,"windchill_c":3.7,"windchill_f":38.7,"heatindex_c":4.4,"heatindex_f":39.9,"dewpoint_c":2.0,"dewpoint_f":35.6,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":0,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":4.3,"gust_kph":6.8,"uv":1.0},{"time_epoch":1649714400,"time":"2022-04-12 01:00","temp_c":3.7,"temp_f":38.7,"is_day":0,"condition":{"text":"Clear","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png","code":1000},"wind_mph":3.4,"wind_kph":5.4,"wind_degree":262,"wind_dir":"W","pressure_mb":1021.0,"pressure_in":30.15,"precip_mm":0.0,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":87,"cloud":22,"feelslike_c":2.5,"feelslike_f":36.5,"windchill_c":2.5,"windchill_f":36.5,"heatindex_c":3.7,"heatindex_f":38.7,"dewpoint_c":1.8,"dewpoint_f":35.2,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":0,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":5.6,"gust_kph":9.0,"uv":1.0},{"time_epoch":1649718000,"time":"2022-04-12 02:00","temp_c":3.3,"temp_f":37.9,"is_day":0,"condition":{"text":"Patchy rain possible","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/176.png","code":1063},"wind_mph":3.1,"wind_kph":5.0,"wind_degree":247,"wind_dir":"WSW","pressure_mb":1021.0,"pressure_in":30.16,"precip_mm":0.2,"precip_in":0.01,"humidity":89,"cloud":78,"feelslike_c":2.1,"feelslike_f":35.8,"windchill_c":2.1,"windchill_f":35.8,"heatindex_c":3.3,"heatindex_f":37.9,"dewpoint_c":1.7,"dewpoint_f":35.1,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":65,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":9.0,"vis_miles":5.0,"gust_mph":5.4,"gust_kph":8.6,"uv":1.0},{"time_epoch":1649721600,"time":"2022-04-12 03:00","temp_c":3.3,"temp_f":37.9,"is_day":0,"condition":{"text":"Partly cloudy","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png","code":1003},"wind_mph":2.5,"wind_kph":4.0,"wind_degree":240,"wind_dir":"WSW","pressure_mb":1022.0,"pressure_in":30.16,"precip_mm":0.0,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":90,"cloud":38,"feelslike_c":2.6,"feelslike_f":36.7,"windchill_c":2.6,"windchill_f":36.7,"heatindex_c":3.3,"heatindex_f":37.9,"dewpoint_c":1.8,"dewpoint_f":35.2,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":0,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":4.0,"gust_kph":6.5,"uv":1.0},{"time_epoch":1649725200,"time":"2022-04-12 04:00","temp_c":3.6,"temp_f":38.5,"is_day":0,"condition":{"text":"Partly cloudy","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png","code":1003},"wind_mph":2.2,"wind_kph":3.6,"wind_degree":234,"wind_dir":"SW","pressure_mb":1021.0,"pressure_in":30.16,"precip_mm":0.0,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":90,"cloud":38,"feelslike_c":3.1,"feelslike_f":37.6,"windchill_c":3.1,"windchill_f":37.6,"heatindex_c":3.6,"heatindex_f":38.5,"dewpoint_c":2.2,"dewpoint_f":36.0,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":0,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":3.6,"gust_kph":5.8,"uv":1.0},{"time_epoch":1649728800,"time":"2022-04-12 05:00","temp_c":3.7,"temp_f":38.7,"is_day":0,"condition":{"text":"Cloudy","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/119.png","code":1006},"wind_mph":2.2,"wind_kph":3.6,"wind_degree":233,"wind_dir":"SW","pressure_mb":1022.0,"pressure_in":30.17,"precip_mm":0.0,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":90,"cloud":86,"feelslike_c":3.3,"feelslike_f":37.9,"windchill_c":3.3,"windchill_f":37.9,"heatindex_c":3.7,"heatindex_f":38.7,"dewpoint_c":2.3,"dewpoint_f":36.1,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":0,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":3.6,"gust_kph":5.8,"uv":1.0},{"time_epoch":1649732400,"time":"2022-04-12 06:00","temp_c":3.9,"temp_f":39.0,"is_day":0,"condition":{"text":"Cloudy","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/119.png","code":1006},"wind_mph":2.0,"wind_kph":3.2,"wind_degree":242,"wind_dir":"WSW","pressure_mb":1022.0,"pressure_in":30.18,"precip_mm":0.0,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":89,"cloud":77,"feelslike_c":3.7,"feelslike_f":38.7,"windchill_c":3.7,"windchill_f":38.7,"heatindex_c":3.9,"heatindex_f":39.0,"dewpoint_c":2.3,"dewpoint_f":36.1,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":0,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":3.1,"gust_kph":5.0,"uv":1.0},{"time_epoch":1649736000,"time":"2022-04-12 07:00","temp_c":4.9,"temp_f":40.8,"is_day":1,"condition":{"text":"Cloudy","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/119.png","code":1006},"wind_mph":2.2,"wind_kph":3.6,"wind_degree":267,"wind_dir":"W","pressure_mb":1022.0,"pressure_in":30.19,"precip_mm":0.0,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":84,"cloud":73,"feelslike_c":4.6,"feelslike_f":40.3,"windchill_c":4.6,"windchill_f":40.3,"heatindex_c":4.9,"heatindex_f":40.8,"dewpoint_c":2.4,"dewpoint_f":36.3,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":0,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":3.1,"gust_kph":5.0,"uv":1.0},{"time_epoch":1649739600,"time":"2022-04-12 08:00","temp_c":6.2,"temp_f":43.2,"is_day":1,"condition":{"text":"Patchy rain possible","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/176.png","code":1063},"wind_mph":3.4,"wind_kph":5.4,"wind_degree":283,"wind_dir":"WNW","pressure_mb":1022.0,"pressure_in":30.19,"precip_mm":0.1,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":76,"cloud":69,"feelslike_c":5.3,"feelslike_f":41.5,"windchill_c":5.3,"windchill_f":41.5,"heatindex_c":6.2,"heatindex_f":43.2,"dewpoint_c":2.3,"dewpoint_f":36.1,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":56,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":4.0,"gust_kph":6.5,"uv":2.0},{"time_epoch":1649743200,"time":"2022-04-12 09:00","temp_c":7.3,"temp_f":45.1,"is_day":1,"condition":{"text":"Patchy rain possible","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/176.png","code":1063},"wind_mph":3.8,"wind_kph":6.1,"wind_degree":295,"wind_dir":"WNW","pressure_mb":1022.0,"pressure_in":30.19,"precip_mm":0.1,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":67,"cloud":83,"feelslike_c":6.3,"feelslike_f":43.3,"windchill_c":6.3,"windchill_f":43.3,"heatindex_c":7.3,"heatindex_f":45.1,"dewpoint_c":1.6,"dewpoint_f":34.9,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":67,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":4.5,"gust_kph":7.2,"uv":2.0},{"time_epoch":1649746800,"time":"2022-04-12 10:00","temp_c":7.7,"temp_f":45.9,"is_day":1,"condition":{"text":"Patchy rain possible","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/176.png","code":1063},"wind_mph":4.5,"wind_kph":7.2,"wind_degree":306,"wind_dir":"NW","pressure_mb":1023.0,"pressure_in":30.19,"precip_mm":0.1,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":62,"cloud":83,"feelslike_c":6.5,"feelslike_f":43.7,"windchill_c":6.5,"windchill_f":43.7,"heatindex_c":7.7,"heatindex_f":45.9,"dewpoint_c":1.0,"dewpoint_f":33.8,"will_it_rain":1,"chance_of_rain":81,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":5.6,"gust_kph":9.0,"uv":2.0},{"time_epoch":1649750400,"time":"2022-04-12 11:00","temp_c":8.2,"temp_f":46.8,"is_day":1,"condition":{"text":"Patchy rain possible","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/176.png","code":1063},"wind_mph":5.4,"wind_kph":8.6,"wind_degree":311,"wind_dir":"NW","pressure_mb":1022.0,"pressure_in":30.18,"precip_mm":0.4,"precip_in":0.02,"humidity":61,"cloud":81,"feelslike_c":6.8,"feelslike_f":44.2,"windchill_c":6.8,"windchill_f":44.2,"heatindex_c":8.2,"heatindex_f":46.8,"dewpoint_c":1.1,"dewpoint_f":34.0,"will_it_rain":1,"chance_of_rain":80,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":9.0,"vis_miles":5.0,"gust_mph":6.7,"gust_kph":10.8,"uv":2.0},{"time_epoch":1649754000,"time":"2022-04-12 12:00","temp_c":8.9,"temp_f":48.0,"is_day":1,"condition":{"text":"Patchy rain possible","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/176.png","code":1063},"wind_mph":6.0,"wind_kph":9.7,"wind_degree":315,"wind_dir":"NW","pressure_mb":1022.0,"pressure_in":30.17,"precip_mm":0.2,"precip_in":0.01,"humidity":59,"cloud":71,"feelslike_c":7.4,"feelslike_f":45.3,"windchill_c":7.4,"windchill_f":45.3,"heatindex_c":8.9,"heatindex_f":48.0,"dewpoint_c":1.4,"dewpoint_f":34.5,"will_it_rain":1,"chance_of_rain":74,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":9.0,"vis_miles":5.0,"gust_mph":7.6,"gust_kph":12.2,"uv":2.0},{"time_epoch":1649757600,"time":"2022-04-12 13:00","temp_c":9.2,"temp_f":48.6,"is_day":1,"condition":{"text":"Patchy rain possible","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/176.png","code":1063},"wind_mph":6.7,"wind_kph":10.8,"wind_degree":317,"wind_dir":"NW","pressure_mb":1022.0,"pressure_in":30.16,"precip_mm":0.2,"precip_in":0.01,"humidity":59,"cloud":82,"feelslike_c":7.5,"feelslike_f":45.5,"windchill_c":7.5,"windchill_f":45.5,"heatindex_c":9.2,"heatindex_f":48.6,"dewpoint_c":1.7,"dewpoint_f":35.1,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":62,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":9.0,"vis_miles":5.0,"gust_mph":8.5,"gust_kph":13.7,"uv":2.0},{"time_epoch":1649761200,"time":"2022-04-12 14:00","temp_c":11.0,"temp_f":51.8,"is_day":1,"condition":{"text":"Patchy rain possible","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/176.png","code":1063},"wind_mph":6.9,"wind_kph":11.2,"wind_degree":320,"wind_dir":"NW","pressure_mb":1021.0,"pressure_in":30.15,"precip_mm":0.9,"precip_in":0.04,"humidity":58,"cloud":71,"feelslike_c":9.7,"feelslike_f":49.5,"windchill_c":9.7,"windchill_f":49.5,"heatindex_c":11.0,"heatindex_f":51.8,"dewpoint_c":3.0,"dewpoint_f":37.4,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":63,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":9.0,"vis_miles":5.0,"gust_mph":8.9,"gust_kph":14.4,"uv":3.0},{"time_epoch":1649764800,"time":"2022-04-12 15:00","temp_c":11.1,"temp_f":52.0,"is_day":1,"condition":{"text":"Sunny","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png","code":1000},"wind_mph":6.7,"wind_kph":10.8,"wind_degree":322,"wind_dir":"NW","pressure_mb":1021.0,"pressure_in":30.14,"precip_mm":0.0,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":57,"cloud":17,"feelslike_c":9.8,"feelslike_f":49.6,"windchill_c":9.8,"windchill_f":49.6,"heatindex_c":11.1,"heatindex_f":52.0,"dewpoint_c":3.0,"dewpoint_f":37.4,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":0,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":7.8,"gust_kph":12.6,"uv":4.0},{"time_epoch":1649768400,"time":"2022-04-12 16:00","temp_c":10.9,"temp_f":51.6,"is_day":1,"condition":{"text":"Sunny","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png","code":1000},"wind_mph":6.3,"wind_kph":10.1,"wind_degree":322,"wind_dir":"NW","pressure_mb":1021.0,"pressure_in":30.14,"precip_mm":0.0,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":57,"cloud":18,"feelslike_c":9.7,"feelslike_f":49.5,"windchill_c":9.7,"windchill_f":49.5,"heatindex_c":10.9,"heatindex_f":51.6,"dewpoint_c":2.7,"dewpoint_f":36.9,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":0,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":7.2,"gust_kph":11.5,"uv":4.0},{"time_epoch":1649772000,"time":"2022-04-12 17:00","temp_c":10.4,"temp_f":50.7,"is_day":1,"condition":{"text":"Patchy rain possible","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/176.png","code":1063},"wind_mph":5.6,"wind_kph":9.0,"wind_degree":322,"wind_dir":"NW","pressure_mb":1021.0,"pressure_in":30.14,"precip_mm":0.1,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":59,"cloud":84,"feelslike_c":9.3,"feelslike_f":48.7,"windchill_c":9.3,"windchill_f":48.7,"heatindex_c":10.4,"heatindex_f":50.7,"dewpoint_c":2.7,"dewpoint_f":36.9,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":63,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":6.5,"gust_kph":10.4,"uv":3.0},{"time_epoch":1649775600,"time":"2022-04-12 18:00","temp_c":9.6,"temp_f":49.3,"is_day":1,"condition":{"text":"Sunny","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png","code":1000},"wind_mph":3.8,"wind_kph":6.1,"wind_degree":331,"wind_dir":"NNW","pressure_mb":1021.0,"pressure_in":30.15,"precip_mm":0.0,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":69,"cloud":8,"feelslike_c":9.0,"feelslike_f":48.2,"windchill_c":9.0,"windchill_f":48.2,"heatindex_c":9.6,"heatindex_f":49.3,"dewpoint_c":4.1,"dewpoint_f":39.4,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":0,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":4.5,"gust_kph":7.2,"uv":3.0},{"time_epoch":1649779200,"time":"2022-04-12 19:00","temp_c":8.1,"temp_f":46.6,"is_day":1,"condition":{"text":"Sunny","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png","code":1000},"wind_mph":1.6,"wind_kph":2.5,"wind_degree":350,"wind_dir":"N","pressure_mb":1022.0,"pressure_in":30.16,"precip_mm":0.0,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":73,"cloud":7,"feelslike_c":8.1,"feelslike_f":46.6,"windchill_c":8.1,"windchill_f":46.6,"heatindex_c":8.1,"heatindex_f":46.6,"dewpoint_c":3.6,"dewpoint_f":38.5,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":0,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":2.0,"gust_kph":3.2,"uv":3.0},{"time_epoch":1649782800,"time":"2022-04-12 20:00","temp_c":6.1,"temp_f":43.0,"is_day":0,"condition":{"text":"Patchy rain possible","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/176.png","code":1063},"wind_mph":1.1,"wind_kph":1.8,"wind_degree":84,"wind_dir":"E","pressure_mb":1022.0,"pressure_in":30.19,"precip_mm":0.1,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":74,"cloud":76,"feelslike_c":6.1,"feelslike_f":43.0,"windchill_c":6.1,"windchill_f":43.0,"heatindex_c":6.1,"heatindex_f":43.0,"dewpoint_c":1.9,"dewpoint_f":35.4,"will_it_rain":1,"chance_of_rain":73,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":2.0,"gust_kph":3.2,"uv":1.0},{"time_epoch":1649786400,"time":"2022-04-12 21:00","temp_c":5.8,"temp_f":42.4,"is_day":0,"condition":{"text":"Clear","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png","code":1000},"wind_mph":1.6,"wind_kph":2.5,"wind_degree":135,"wind_dir":"SE","pressure_mb":1022.0,"pressure_in":30.19,"precip_mm":0.0,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":75,"cloud":17,"feelslike_c":5.8,"feelslike_f":42.4,"windchill_c":5.8,"windchill_f":42.4,"heatindex_c":5.8,"heatindex_f":42.4,"dewpoint_c":1.7,"dewpoint_f":35.1,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":0,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":2.7,"gust_kph":4.3,"uv":1.0},{"time_epoch":1649790000,"time":"2022-04-12 22:00","temp_c":5.6,"temp_f":42.1,"is_day":0,"condition":{"text":"Clear","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png","code":1000},"wind_mph":1.1,"wind_kph":1.8,"wind_degree":158,"wind_dir":"SSE","pressure_mb":1022.0,"pressure_in":30.19,"precip_mm":0.0,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":74,"cloud":16,"feelslike_c":5.6,"feelslike_f":42.1,"windchill_c":5.6,"windchill_f":42.1,"heatindex_c":5.6,"heatindex_f":42.1,"dewpoint_c":1.4,"dewpoint_f":34.5,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":0,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":2.0,"gust_kph":3.2,"uv":1.0},{"time_epoch":1649793600,"time":"2022-04-12 23:00","temp_c":5.4,"temp_f":41.7,"is_day":0,"condition":{"text":"Partly cloudy","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png","code":1003},"wind_mph":0.2,"wind_kph":0.4,"wind_degree":13,"wind_dir":"NNE","pressure_mb":1023.0,"pressure_in":30.2,"precip_mm":0.0,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":73,"cloud":28,"feelslike_c":5.4,"feelslike_f":41.7,"windchill_c":5.4,"windchill_f":41.7,"heatindex_c":5.4,"heatindex_f":41.7,"dewpoint_c":1.0,"dewpoint_f":33.8,"will_it_rain":0,"chance_of_rain":0,"will_it_snow":0,"chance_of_snow":0,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0,"gust_mph":0.4,"gust_kph":0.7,"uv":1.0}]}]}}
```

I tried to access date element this way but this method is too confused. Do I have to create a model that fits response?
I think there must be a better way

```java
@Override
    public WeatherForecast getDailyWeatherForecast()  {
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity =
                restTemplate.
                        getForEntity("http://api.weatherapi.com" +
                                        "/v1/forecast.json?" +
                                        "q=Bursa&key=f3fa95e96b0b404e825193304221104&days=1",
                                String.class);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try{Map<String,Map<String, Map>> map = objectMapper.readValue(responseEntity.getBody(), Map.class);

        System.out.println(map.get("forecast").get("forecastday").get("0"));
        }
        catch(JsonProcessingException e) {
                    log.info(e.getMessage());
        }


        return new WeatherForecastImpl(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),
                "Sunny",25,20,50);

    }
```

Comment: Please post the JSON here, not a link which is not even HTTPS, and also show at least your first attempt

Comment: it's not that big...

Comment: sorry, i added json data now

Comment: i also added my first solution method

Comment: The field forecast.forecastday is a list. What if it's empty? What if there is more than one element?

Comment: i know so my solution is not working i couldnt think any other way idk how can i solve it

Comment: It is technically possible, but you should have a functional specification in mind. What do you want to do with the date? If there is more than one, you want to take the last? The first? If there is none, you want to throw an exception? Those specifications can only come from you...

Comment: i just want to access date object i can handle the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is to create a class (annotated with `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to skip all the elements of the Json I don't need):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Response {

    @JsonProperty("forecast")
    private final Forecast forecast;

    @JsonCreator
    public Response(@JsonProperty(value = "forecast", required = true) Forecast forecast) {
        this.forecast = forecast;
    }

    public Optional<String> getDate() {
        if (forecast.forecastDays.isEmpty()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return Optional.of(forecast.forecastDays.get(forecast.forecastDays.size() - 1).date);
    }

    public static class Forecast {
        @JsonProperty("forecastday")
        private final List<ForecastDay> forecastDays;

        @JsonCreator
        public Forecast(@JsonProperty(value = "forecastday", required = true) List<ForecastDay> forecastDays) {
            this.forecastDays = forecastDays;
        }
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class ForecastDay {
        @JsonProperty("date")
        private final String date;

        @JsonCreator
        public ForecastDay(@JsonProperty(value = "date", required = true) String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I would ask Jackson to parse the received Json response against such object and I would get the date through that:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Response response = objectMapper.readValue(responseEntity.getBody(), Response.class);
String date = response.getDate().orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No date found"));
```

The method `Optional<String> getDate()` that I added to the `Response` class will return an empty optional in case no forecastday is in the list, else it will return the last element of the list (in absence of specifications, I took this assumption).

Disclaimer: I wrote the code directly on StackOverflow, that means there may be some little syntax mistakes. I let you handle that part.

Comment: I got this error java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.isEmpty()" because "this.forecast.forecastDays" is null

Comment: @EmirhanAy answer edited, now it should work